# Loading a file from page methods

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, pagemethods

I have a JavaScript function which calls a page method as follows:

```
function openFile(file) {
    PageMethods.LoadFile(file);
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void LoadFile(string fileName)
{
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
   HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
   HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/binary";
   var filePath = @"C:\MyFiles\" + fileName;
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
   HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(filePath);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

The page method throws the following exception:

**Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'LoadFile' failed with the following error: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException-- Thread was being aborted.**

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

You get this Exception because you have call the End() and you force the abort.

**HttpContext.Current.Response.End();**

Just remove it.

Reference : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629/
And if you google it: **HttpContext.Current.Response.End**

### update

I see now that you try to send a file, but you have set the path to your local disk. Change that to your http address.

Comment: Also if you really want to end the request, use this instead: HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

Comment: using HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest() no longer throws the thread abort exception but at the same time the file is not sent to the browser.

Comment: @Kumar the file is not send the way you try to do it. For sure you have made a mistake because here you have place the local disk directory !. For send the file open a new question - I just see here that you have place the wrong path.